# Is there a better way to pass variables to my view?

Tags: java, java-ee-6

My gripe with the below code is that the variables `template` and `urlPrefix` have to be called via `<%=request.getAttribute('urlPrefix')%>`.  Is there a way for me to pass a variable so I can just call it like `<%=urlPrefix%>` ?

```
public void loadView (PageConfig config) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = config.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = config.getResponse();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("base.jsp");

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    request.setAttribute("template", config.getTemplate());
    request.setAttribute("urlPrefix", "/CMS");

    System.out.println("Controller::LoadView()");

    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: I'd consider localizing your variable declarations, especially the dispatcher.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Can you give me some more detail on what you mean by localizing them?  I don't like linking them to the request, but I don't know of any other way to get the jsp to use them

Comment: I just mean declare them near where they're used; sorry. It just makes thinking about code easier is all.

Comment: @DaveNewton - You're saying just declare them in the .jsp file?  If that was an option, I'd of course do that.  But I need a way to define variables in my controllers and be usable within my views.

Comment: ... I'm saying in your Java, declare your variables near where they're used. Keeping things near where they're used makes reading code easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSP EL. Scriptlets are kind of... frowned upon, and clunky.

```
${urlPrefix}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSP scriptlets are not the way to go, modern Java EE applications use expression language for accessing variables; the syntax is `#{urlPrefix}` . Also consider using Java Server Faces (JSF) for implementing navigation and separate the view from the business logic.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/help/jsp-jsfel/jsf_expression_language_intro.html) for further details.

Comment: Are you saying that modern applications no longer use MVC?  Just MV?  It looks like JSF eliminates the controller from the equation.

Comment: @Webnet JSF is component-oriented, arguably a better fit with modern web apps. There's a lot of MVC/action-oriented frameworks in common use--JSF is just another option.